# Show the set is neither closed nor open but the union set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

[Question]

1) Show that the set $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

2) Show the set $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$

[Solution]

1)

**Open**

A set is open M is open, if for every $x_0 \in M$ exists an $r>0$ such that the open ball $B_r(x_0) \subset M$.

Show the set is not open by contraction.

Define $M=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Assume M is open then we have an $r>0$. Now let's evalutater the ball with center in 1 with some r>0. 
$B_r(1)$. Given that $M≤1$ and $r>0$ we can conclude that $B_r(1) \not\subset M$ and therefore we have a contradiction.

**Closed**

Show m is not closed. We assume M is closed, meaning every convergent sequence in $M$ also has a limit contained in $M$

We have the sequence $\frac{1}{n}\in M$ with $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0 \not\in M$. Therefore we have a contradiction and $M$ is not closed.

2) I'm uncertain about (2). But here is what I tried.

A set is closed if the complement is open.

I know the complement is the interval of $(-∞;0) \cup (1;∞)$ which is open. 
But I'm uncertain of how to prove that that is the complement and whether it is open or not.

---

I'm uncertain if the proofs hold up or if they are too informal. I'm also not 100% certain how to prove 2). Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For $2$, one method is to show that its complement is open.

Comment: @ElliotG, that is what I was thinking. However I'm uncertain how to do it. Normally I let $z \in M^c$ but what would the radius in this case be? I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @Bungo do you have any advise on what an appropriate radius would be?

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 is fine, apart from some details: $M\le1$ is incorrect notation and is not relevant anyway: the ball $B_1(1)$ certainly contains points not in $M$, take for example $9/10$.

In order to show that $M'=M\cup\{0\}$ is closed, note that if $x$ is a limit point of $M'$ there would be a subsequence of $(1/n)$ converging to $x$.

Comment: So i need to prove what the limit point of $M'$ is and then prove that a subsequence of $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to that limit point? 
I'm not sure I understand how to prove it, do you have any advise?

Comment: @user422982 Any subsequence of a convergent sequence converges at the same limit.

Comment: I see  no errors in the OP's proof of (2), although  it can be done more succintly:  There is a sequence in $M$ converging to  $0$ ,and $0\not \in M.$ Therefore  $M$ is not closed.

Comment: @user254665 Did I say it was incorrect? Part 2 is proving that $M\cup\{0\}$ is closed.

Comment: @egreg. No you didn't say it was incorrect